# Dozer Mapper does not map despite fields having same names and XML mappings specified

Tags: java, mapping, converters, dozer, mapper

### Supposing I have:

1. **ObjectWithList**, **ListWrapper** and **ObjectWithWrapper** classes like these:

```java
//com.github.komidawi.ObjectWithList
public class ObjectWithList {
    private List<String> list;
    // ...
}

//com.github.komidawi.ListWrapper 
public class ListWrapper {
    private List<String> wrappedList;
    // ...
}

//com.github.komidawi.ObjectWithWrapper
public class ObjectWithWrapper {
    private ListWrapper list;
    // ...
}
```

2. **MyCustomConverter** class to wrap/unwrap these lists.
3. **mapperConfiguration.xml** configuration file

```xml
<!-- ... -->
<configuration>
    <stop-on-errors>true</stop-on-errors>
    <wildcard>true</wildcard>

    <custom-converters>
        <converter type="com.github.komidawi.MyCustomConverter">
            <class-a>com.github.komidawi.ListWrapper</class-a>
            <class-b>java.util.List</class-b>
        </converter>
    </custom-converters>
</converter>

<mapping>
        <class-a>com.github.komidawi.ObjectWithList</class-a>
        <class-b>com.github.komidawi.ObjectWithWrapper</class-b>
</mapping>
```

---

### And I want to map **ObjectWithWrapper** to **ObjectWithList**:

```java
// ... creating objects
ObjectWithList objectWithList = mapper.map(objectWithWrapper, ObjectWithList.class);
objectWithList.getList(); // This is null
```

Unfortunately, after mapping, **list** field of objectWithList is **null**.
I used debugger and it Dozer doesn't even enter **MyCustomConverter** in this case.

Surprisingly, mapping in different direction works fine:

```java
ObjectWithWrapper objecthWithWrapper = mapper.map(objectWithList, ObjectWithWrapper.class);
objecthWithWrapper.getList(); // This is not null
```

---

### Summarizing:

1. Field name is the same both in **ObjectWithList** and **ObjectWithWrapper**: *list*
2. I have specified custom converter for Java's **List** and **ListWrapper** in xml file
3. I have specified mapping between **ObjectWithList** and **ObjectWithWrapper** in xml file
4. In both cases Dozer says: *"Successfully loaded custom xml mappings from URL"*
5. When mapping from **ObjectWithList** to **ObjectWithWrapper** it works fine

---

### And the problem is:

After mapping, **objectWithList** has **null** instead of actual list. I spotted that it doesn't even enter **MyCustomConverter**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Collections are special and the type erasure makes them more challenging. If all you want is for the items in wrappedList to be in the list in the resulting ObjectWithList instance, this can be accomplished without the converter. Dozer will handle nested property mapping, so you can describe the mapping in such a way that instructs Dozer to map the lists to each other.

```
new BeanMappingBuilder() {
    configure() {
        mapping(ObjectWithList.class, ObjectWithWrapper.class,
            .fields("list.wrappedList", "list")
    }
}
```

or in XML

```
<mapping>
        <class-a>com.github.komidawi.ObjectWithList</class-a>
        <class-b>com.github.komidawi.ObjectWithWrapper</class-b>
        <field>
            <a>list.wrappedList</a>
            <b>list</b>
        </field>
</mapping>
```

Comment: Assuming that `wrappedList` is type `List<A>` and `list` is type `List<B>`, would it be possible without using custom converter to achieve `ObjectWithList` to `ObjectWithWrapper` mapping with `A` to `B` list elements mapping as well ?

Comment: @komidawi Yes. Dozer will then loop through the list and map each element A in the source to an element B instance in the destination.

Comment: @komidawi Did this solve your issue?  I would appreciate it if you would accept the answer.  Thank you John

Comment: It is indeed possible to avoid using custom converter - I just needed to explicitly specify all fields in XML file. Thanks!